# Laravel authentication and AWS Cognito: why do people use guards?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We would like to use Cognito to keep our users in a specific database, mainly to be able to remove/add users directly from AWS.

I've found some repositories implementing new guards to communicate with Cognito.

As far as I understand, guards are responsible of checking if the authentication is correct, and user providers are responsible of getting the user data from some place.

Why do everybody create custom guards, and not custom user providers?

If you only create a custom guard, you will use the Eloquent Provider, meaning all your Cognito data will also be in your database.

I think a custom `UserProvider` seems what we need here, to get the data from Cognito and just check if the inputted credentials are valid or not.

Is there something I am misunderstanding?

A few examples:

https://github.com/black-bits/laravel-cognito-auth

https://github.com/Pod-Point/laravel-cognito-auth

https://github.com/ArranJacques/laravel-aws-cognito-auth

Comment: perhaps they want to use conginto SSO features and avoid calling congnito API when application needs information on user such as name, email, etc... to send emails or notifications